# Auto Hide/Unhide Rows 1 -100 based on value of cell in first column

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a sheet that I have the first cell A1 given a number of either 0 or 1 based upon input from another sheet depending on a selection from the user.

If the cell A1 changes to 0 then the entire row is hidden.

I am using the following below and it works fine Auto/hiding the row.

What I am looking to do now is have the row unhide if the same cell changes from 0 to 1.

Thanks for any help! Here's the file...
http://jmp.sh/89BVI0A

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, [A:A]) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Rows.Hidden = UCase(Target.Value) = "0"
    End If
End Sub
```

A copy of the spreadsheet can be found [here](http://jmp.sh/89BVI0A).

Comment: Hello fixer1234. I'm trying to do both. I want to Auto/Hide and Auto Unhide depending on whether the cell A1 is either 0 or 1 in the range of A1:A100. Everything I've tried doesn't work. This is the only thing I've come up with that at least is hiding properly. Any help on the unhiding part would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens with the formula you show here when A1 is 1?  What triggers action when A1 changes?

Comment: When A1 cell changes to 0 the row is hidden. When it changes back to 1, I need the row to Unhide but it doesn't. The cell A1 is determined by another selection from another sheet. Essentially input from the user.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that nothing is triggering the macro to reassess.  It runs once, perhaps based on conditions when you open the workbook, and then nothing makes it run again.  You probably need to include a trigger based on change.  Test by manually forcing the macro to run after you change A1 from 0 to 1.

Comment: Is there a way I could send you the file for you to see?

Comment: Post the file on a sharing site, or if you have a Google account, see if it can be imported into a Google spreadsheet with sharing enabled.  Add a link to it in the question.  The edit will also bump the question on the main page and get some more eyes on it.  Also, add a tag for the spreadsheet application / version you're using.

Comment: Here you go. http://jmp.sh/89BVI0A

Comment: It's an Excel 2013 Spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in `Sheet2` Module

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()    'Sheet2 Module

    Const FC = "A"    'Filter Column

    Dim lr As Long, filterCol As Range

    lr = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, FC).End(xlUp).Row      'Determine last cell in ColA

    Set filterCol = Me.Range(Me.Cells(1, FC), Me.Cells(lr, FC)) 'ColA "UsedRange"

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        filterCol.Formula = "=Sheet1!A1"                'Update all formulas
        filterCol.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1"   'Show only rows where ColA = 1
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

---

This will capture the user interaction in `Sheet1` that updates the formulas in `Sheet2`

It will hide all rows with value `0` in `Sheet2.colA`

Comment: Hello Paul Bica. Thanks for the help. I appreciate how you showed me how to describe the issue better. I will try to format in a similar way in any future questions I post. I'm new here, sorry. Also I love how efficient your idea solution is and it certain works. I suspect my real trouble is triggering the event.

Comment: The reason I put in the data validation is because the value in cell A1:A20 on Sheet 1 needs to get it's final value by formula in another cell. Imagine it this way. and I probably should have made the shared file in this manner, that the data validation was an a third sheet "Sheet 3" which filled in the value on Sheet 1 which Auto/hides or unhides the row(s) on Sheet 2. Any more help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @klocksbass - I updated the answer for `Sheet2` to trigger  an `AutoFilter` in the `Worksheet_Calculate()` events (when `Sheet1` is updated by the user)

Comment: @pual_bica What a great idea and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @klocksbass you may accept the answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It'll remove this question from SU 'unanswered' list. ( :